# `if` condition remains borrowed in body

Tags: rust

I just came across some behaviour in Rust (1.12) I cannot explain. I have a struct that implements lazy loading with a `RefCell<Option<i32>>` and a function to access the data:

```
struct Foo {
    data: RefCell<Option<i32>>
}

impl Foo {
    fn get_data(&self) -> i32 {
        if self.data.borrow().is_none() { // <--- (a)
            let d = 1337;
            self.data.borrow_mut() = Some(d); // <--- (b)
            d
        } else {
            self.data.borrow().unwrap()
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles but yields a runtime error: The `RefCell` complains that a borrow is already active when attempting to `borrow_mut` on line **(b)**. The issue does not occur, however, if I change the if statement to the following:

```
let is_none = self.data.borrow().is_none();
if is_none {
```

**Question:** Why is the borrow in the if condition on line **(a)** still active inside the body of the if statement? Shouldn't the call to `is_none()` cause the borrow to end, since I'm only holding on to a `bool` afterwards, and not the borrowed value?

Comment: Looks like it fixed in Beta and Nightly. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=450c131dcefde855ea0cbd832290e046&version=nightly&backtrace=0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to Rust's lexical borrowing scope.

As you have noticed, borrowing something in the condition also borrows it for the branch. This is discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/6393), and has since moved [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/811).

This is a limitation that is currently fixed in the Rust 1.13 Beta and will thus probably be released in the next cycle.